# When does a descending sequence of nonempty sets have a non empty intersection?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $\langle F_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ be a descending sequence of nonempty sets in a Metric Space - $F_1\supset F_2\supset\cdots$. What are the conditions on the underlying space so that  $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n\ne \emptyset$?

On the one hand I know compactness of the space is sufficient, but I think it's not necessary. It seems that if I'm dealing with a metric space, and the space isn't complete then this doesn't hold either (simple counter examples in $\mathbb{Q}$). But is completeness sufficient? How is this formally shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The completness is sufficient if the diameters of $F_n$ tends to $0$. Find a Cauchy sequence which has a limit in the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Compactness of the space is not sufficient. Take, for example, $$F_1=\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots\}\\
F_2=\{\frac12,\frac13,\dots\}\\
\vdots\\
F_n=\{\frac1n,\frac{1}{n+1},\dots\}\\
\vdots$$

for which the intersection is an empty set.

---

But what about if the sets are closed? Well then completeness will not be enough to provide you with an empty intersection, as the example of $F_n=[n,\infty)\subset\mathbb R$ clearly shows.

Comment: You're right, I think I need to add a condition on the sets that they be closed...

Comment: @user126743 I added an example using closed sets which does not work in a non-compact space. In a compact space using closed sets, however, the intersection will not be empty.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess that I must either require closed sets + compactness, or converging diameter + completeness?